# Collatz 3n+1 problem

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, collatz-conjecture

Does it suffice to say that, using the tree/reverse of 3n+1 problem, if we can show that we can generate all positive integers starting from integer 1, including 1 itself, is equivalent to proving indirectly the Collatz Conjecture?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: yes, exactly, like say  a generator: g(1) = {x | x∈ℕ}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can indeed easily rephrase the Collatz conjecture to be about trying to generate every number starting from $1$ by applying a couple operations, but you have to be careful what you mean by "generate."

Let $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)={x-1\over 3}$. It's natural to try to walk from $1$ to $n$ via $f$ and $g$ to show that $n$ isn't a counterexample to Collatz, but this doesn't always go smoothly: e.g. $g$ lets us map $13$ to $4$, but in a Collatz sequence we'll never go from $4$ to $13$ since $4$ is even (we would go instead from $4$ to $2$). So starting from $1$ and applying $f$ and $g$ repeatedly to get $n$ does *not* necessarily show that $n$ isn't a counterexample to Collatz, since when we reverse this walk we might get a sequence which doesn't follow the rules.

Specifically, *we can never apply $g$ if the result will be even*. The following is true:

> Suppose there is a sequence $a_1,..., a_k$ with $a_1=1$, $a_k=n$, for each $i$ we have $a_{i+1}=f(a_i)$ or $a_{i+1}=g(a_i)$, *and* whenever $a_{i+1}$ is even we have $a_{i+1}=f(a_i)$. Then $n$ is not a counterexample to Collatz.

However, merely talking about "generating" numbers without this crucial restriction on when we're allowed to apply a given operation gives a very misleading idea.

Comment: yes I definitely agree, and certainly there will be restrictions by properly defining how the generator works in spitting out the set of positive integers, but my main concern is simply, if we have such generator that follows the premise of the conjecture, say there is g(k) = g(1) --> x:x∈ℕ, is that the same as proving the conjecture? To make it precise, we say that on particular operation on g(1) it maps to 3 that in turns 3 maps to 10 then finally 10 maps to 5, all as part of operations that defines the rule for g(1).

Comment: in addition, such generator will map those corresponding integers based on a parameter, k≥1. so for every unique k, g(1) generates corresponding integers.

Comment: You say this doesn't give you Collatz but surprisingly, something very close to it does, which is why I asked this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848468/ I could explain if you would be open to a chat. it can't be done in comments. It turns out all we need is a bijection $\omega^{<\omega}\to\omega$ very similar to the one you described to me on MO.

Comment: hi Robert, yes definitely we can open a chat, I think we can collaborate on this, I have derived and proven a "generator", if that is the right term, that works both in backward/forward iteration and I have shown already that, say, call my set generator g(1) ={x:x∈ℕ), in forward iteration (tree-method)

Comment: I also do the backward iteration (from x to 1) and it works perfectly as per the rule of the conjecture. As a bonus, on the process it naturally produced a result showing that {1,4,2,1} is the only loop cycle. I also have shown that backward iteration is a kind of an equivalence relation satisfying reflexivity, symetric, transitivity, serves as another key of solving the puzzle.